# Javascript: Compare three booleans and return all true booleans

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

I have a method getPreferredfood(). It gets three boolean values that represent different food items. Which ever of them are true, you return those.

```
getPreferredFood: function (){
 var item 1; 
 var item2 ;
 var item3;

 //comparison?

 return "Preferred food is " (whichever item was true)
 }
```

I'm not sure how to return the the item that are true.

Comment: `non-veg` is not valid JS variable name

Comment: Use an array of object like `{type: "vegan", value: true}`. Then you can filter the array.

Comment: How are you setting the variables? If they're coming from checkboxes, why not just get the names of the checked ones, instead of using separate variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the variable name as part of a string output. That's not usually how you want to do things.

Consider doing this instead:

```
var tags = {
    "vegan": true,
    "non-veg": false,
    "veg": false
};

var true_tags = [];
for (var tag in tags) {
    if (tags[tag] === true) {
        true_tags.push(tag);
    }
}

console.log(true_tags); // will print [ "vegan" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Store the values in an object / map:

```
var options = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: false,
};
```

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the names and use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on that array to filter out the ones that are `false`:

```
Object.keys(options).filter(function(x) {
  return options[x];
});
// ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var preferenceValues = {
   'vegan': true,
   'non-veg': false,
   'veg': false
}

function getPreferences(preferenceValues) {
   var preferences = [];

   for(type in preferenceValues) {
      if (preferenceValues[type]) {
          preferences.push(type);
      }
   }

   return 'Person prefers ' + preferences.join(', ') + ' food';
}


console.log(getPreferences(preferenceValues))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to attach your variable to namespace (example: `api`) :

```
     var api={};

    api.vegan= true
    api.non_veg= false
    api.veg = false;
```

Then , what you need is to loop through properties of this namespace and filter true ones .

```
'Person prefers  '+Object.keys(api).filter((ky)=>api[ky]).join(',');
```

If you cannot add it to namespace ,the default namespace is `window` & you need then to have a whitelist to loop on .

## DEMO

```js
var api={};
api.vegan= true;
api.non_veg= false;
api.veg = false;
console.log(
'Person prefers '+ Object.keys(api).filter((ky)=>api[ky]).join(',')
  )
```